# Do Type 1 (Slow Oxidative) muscle fibers also make use of glycolysis?

Tags: human-biology

I'm aware that slow-twitch fibers make use of oxidative phosphorylation; however, I am unsure if this is done in conjunction with glycolysis and the krebs cycle? Do these muscle fibers go through all three stages of aerobic respiration, or just the final step? If not, where are they getting the precursors for oxidative phosphorylation (NADH, FADH2)? Would they use fatty acids and proteins as precursors in the krebs cycle (if applicable)?

Slow-twitch (Type IIB) seem to use glycolysis and then anaerobic respiration (forming lactate), right?

Any input is greatly appreciated!